# ListView Custom row not clickable entirely

Tags: android, android-listview

I am creating an App, in which I am showing information from a database in a ListView, using a custom row layout, which is populated using a SimpleCursorAdapter. I also handle onItemClickListner for the ListView.

My Layout of the custom rows is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:padding="10dip" >

<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageButtonAccount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_account" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextViewAccount"
    style="@style/textView_normal_bold_style"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dip"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But I have one issue, which follows:
When I click above content of ListView row, it performs only click event, but what I want is when I click any where in a row then a click action should be performed. But it does not behave like this.

Comment: did you make your row's width to fill parent ?

Answer (score 0):

The XML of your row should have the attribute

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```